# Exception while connecting to DB on remote server (ASP.NET Web Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I am trying to connect my ASP.NET web Forms app to a SQL Server database on a remote server. I can access the database from SQL Server Management Studio but while debugging it causes an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Here is the code I have tried

```
public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string conStr = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa; Password=Password123; Initial Catalog=RegInfo;Data Source=WIN2008-64-90\\SQLEXPRESS";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Db_Con();
    }

    protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filename));

        Picture.ImageUrl = "~/"+filename;
    }

    public void Db_Con()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: **(1)** never ever use the `Sa` account - not even in testing! **(2)** you're connecting to a "remote" SQL Server Express instance - does this have remote connections enabled? Those are OFF by default ...

Comment: yeah remote connections are on..